Sending attachments using Gmail API with Flutter?
I am successfully sending emails using the Gmail API with Flutter.
How can I modify the following code, to be able to send attachments with the email?
Thanks in advance.
Map<String, String> header = {
  'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
  'X-Goog-AuthUser': xGoogAuthUserHeader,
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
};

String createEmail(
  String to,
  String from,
) {
  return '''
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
to: $to
from: $from
subject: subject

body
''';
}

var formattedEmail = email.createEmail(e, user.email!);

var bytes = utf8.encode(formattedEmail);
var base64 = base64Encode(bytes);
var body = json.encode({'raw': base64});

Uri httpsUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'https',
  host: 'www.googleapis.com',
  path: '/gmail/v1/users/${user.email}/messages/send',
);

await post(
  httpsUri,
  headers: header,
  body: body,
);


how did you get the authorization to work with flutter #justcurous

Now you should be able to send an email and attachments too
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> sendEmailWithAttachment(
  String to,
  String from,
  String subject,
  String body,
  List<File> attachments, // List of attachment files
  String authorizationHeader,
  String xGoogAuthUserHeader,
) async {
  // Construct the email message with attachments
  var boundary = 'boundary-string'; // Set a boundary for multipart content
  var emailContent = '''
--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
to: $to
from: $from
subject: $subject

$body
''';

  // Add attachments to emailContent
  for (var file in attachments) {
    var attachmentContent = await file.readAsBytes();
    var base64Attachment = base64Encode(attachmentContent);
    var filename = file.path.split('/').last;

    emailContent += '''
--$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$filename"

$base64Attachment
''';
  }

  emailContent += '\n--$boundary--'; // End of email boundary

  // Encode emailContent to base64
  var base64Email = base64Encode(utf8.encode(emailContent));

  // Construct HTTP headers
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
    'X-Goog-AuthUser': xGoogAuthUserHeader,
    'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822'
  };

  // Send the email via Gmail API
  var uri = Uri(
    scheme: 'https',
    host: 'www.googleapis.com',
    path: '/gmail/v1/users/$from/messages/send',
  );

  await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonEncode({'raw': base64Email}),
  );
}

void main() async {
  // Usage example
  String to = 'recipient@example.com';
  String from = 'sender@example.com';
  String subject = 'Test email with attachments';
  String body = 'This is a test email with attachments.';
  List<File> attachments = [File('path/to/attachment1.txt'), File('path/to/attachment2.jpg')]; // List of attachment files

  String authorizationHeader = 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER';
  String xGoogAuthUserHeader = 'YOUR_X_GOOG_AUTH_USER_HEADER';

  await sendEmailWithAttachment(to, from, subject, body, attachments, authorizationHeader, xGoogAuthUserHeader);
}


Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I can't use dart:io because I am using Flutter Web and it only supports dart:html. Do you have any idea how I can manage the files using dart:html instead of dart:io? Thanks in advance.
